# What kind of entertainment would be possible in a microbiological world?

Tags: biology, society

Imagine a world in which the structures and resources are our own organs, tissues and cells. The society would be run by special cells and living microorganisms.

My inspiration is from the animation [Ozzy and Drix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozzy_%26_Drix)

I can think of several structures implemented on this world. For example, the heart would be our "water station", while the veins are the plumbing.

Alternatively the heart could be a "Water Park" for entertainment, and the veins rivers with its source at the marrows and with the possibility for rowing and other sports.

What kind of additional entertainment would be possible on this world?

Comment: I am Jack's lack of personal fulfillment.

Answer (score 1):

**Racing**
Race either through the Circulatory, Lymphatic or Nervous Systems.

**Betting on said races**

**Flying**
High risk sport, flying up into the nasal cavities and then grabbing onto (anything) before being ejected out of their world. (When someone is sneezing)

**Wars/Brawls**
With microbes and the such. Fighting could be seen as a thrill, over-viewed by white cells.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly hunting - sign on for a short deployment with the anti-bodies, and kill as many viruses as you can

Tours of other organs and systems

(Permanent) trips to the outside world: get yourself out of the person's body in some way (spit, mucous, other less desirable things, etc...) to see what awaits you in the vast outdoors. No one's ever come back, so it must be a great place.

For the sadistic: play pranks on the human you're inside. Tickle the right nerve to make him certain he just felt his phone vibrate in his pocket, when it's actually on his desk. Make him recognize his ex-girlfriend or dead parent in every somewhat-similar face he passes on the sidewalk. Phantom pains from an amputated limb. Get a bunch of your friends together and make all the muscle cells stop working at the same time so he trips and falls in public.